# Como usar o Distinct() ou GroupBy() em uma lista que retorna um tipo anônimo?

Tags: c#, linq

Estou fazendo um select no banco para trazer o **`IdNavio`** e **`Navio`**, mas não quero trazer os repetidos.

Estou tentando usar os métodos **`Distinct()`** e **`GroupBy()`**, mas não estão funcionando, estou usando o *namespace* **`System.Linq`**.

Exemplo:

```
var listaDeNavios = Context.VWProgramacaoEmbarque
                           .Select(e => new { IdNavio = e.IdNavio, Navio = e.Navio });
```

Tem como fazer usando esses métodos? Ou existe outra forma para esse tipo?

Comment: Qual o problema? Ele continua trazendo duplicatas?

Comment: @GabrielColetta Continua trazendo duplicado.

Comment: IdNavio é uma chave primária?

Comment: @GabrielColetta Na realidade esse select é com base em uma View do banco que tem varios Ids, um deles é o Id do Navio. Pode ser esse o problema ? por ser uma view ?

Comment: teóricamente não, o problema é se for uma chave primária. Posso afirmar que é? Se for já sei o problema

Comment: @GabrielColetta Sim, é uma chave primária.

Comment: @samuelrvg Você quer distinguir por uma propriedade ou pelas duas?

Comment: @LINQ por Id do Navio apenas, mas se possível pelas duas também parece interessante.

Comment: Você sabe que um Id é sempre diferente do outro, correto? Esse é o problema principal do seu Distinct().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quer fazer um *distinct* pela propriedade `NavioId`, você pode agrupar os resultados por esta propriedade e depois usar o método `Distinct`.

Geralmente eu prefiro fazer um método de extensão pra isto

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        return source.GroupBy(keySelector).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
    }
}
```

O uso seria assim

```
var listaDeNavios = Context.VWProgramacaoEmbarque
                       .Select(e => new { IdNavio = e.IdNavio, Navio = e.Navio })
                       .DistinctBy(e => e.IdNavio);
```

Comment: Não funcionou, quando eu transformo em .ToList() gera o seguinte erro: Message "Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 não suporta APPLY" string - Relacionado ao Oracle, irei pesquisar esse erro para entender melhor.

Comment: @samuelrvg Não sabia que teu banco é Oracle, você não vai conseguir fazer o GroupBy com Oracle 11 porque a _query_ que o EF gera tem um `OUTTER APPLY` e teu banco de dados não a suporta.

Comment: Entendi, essa pergunta fala justamente sobre isso https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705013/linq-to-entities-group-by-outer-apply-oracle-11-2-0-3-0-does-not-support-appl

Comment: @samuelrvg Exatamente, eu acho que a melhor ideia pra você é criar uma procedure pra trazer os dados já com _distinct_. Btw, não sei bem como agir com sua pergunta, porque (neste caso) o banco de dados ser Oracle muda todo o percurso das respostas e isso não foi especificado.

Comment: Compreendo, nesse caso irei aceitar sua resposta como solução, pois o problema está no fato do oracle 11g não suportar esse tipo de consulta.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é seu IdNavio ser um valor único. O `Enumerable.Distinct()` utiliza os métodos do Object para fazer seu trabalho. No caso de tipo anônimo o compilador vai sobrescrever o `Object.Equals()` e o `Object.GetHashCode()` e vai comparar **todos** os valores do seu tipo. Já que seu IdNavio sempre vai ter valores diferentes entre si, o mesmo sempre vai ser diferente.

A solução simples seria um IEqualityComparer, porém ele não funcionária já que você tem um tipo anônimo e apenas usando reflexão você conseguiria saber quais propriedades vai participar da comparação, algo parecido com o exemplificado aqui:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94272/A-Generic-IEqualityComparer-for-Linq-Distinct

Logo, a melhor solução, na minha humilde opinião, passa a ser você criar uma classe Command e fazer a sobrescrita dos `Object.Equals()` e `Object.GetHashCode()`, assim implementar o DistinctBy seria bem mais simples:

```
public class NavioComparer : IEqualityComparer<NavioCommand>
{
    public bool Equals(NavioCommand first, NavioCommand second)
    {
        return first.Navio.Equals(second.Navio);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(NavioCommand obj)
    {
        return obj.Navio.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Outros adendos:

- O DistinctBy do MoreLINQ funcionária, porém ele trabalha com IEnumerable, não IQueryable, logo seu Distinct seria executado em memória, não no banco de dados.
- Você também poderia implementar seu proprio DistinctBy que aceite um IQueryable (exemplo do LINQ).